# How can i Consume WebApi Service in mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

Here I'm trying to access `WebApi` Service in `Mvc` but im geeting error :

> asSeverity    Code    Description Project File    Line Error  CS0029  Cannot
>   implicitly convert type 'string' to
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'

```
    IEnumerable<MasterTab> resResult = result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
 public ActionResult Index()
        {
            using(var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:54040/Api/Marketing/");
                var responseTask = client.GetAsync("GetMarketing");
                responseTask.Wait();
                var result = responseTask.Result;
                if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    IEnumerable<MasterTab> resResult = result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                }
                else
                {
                    students = Enumerable.Empty<MasterTab>();ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Server Error Please Conatct Admin");
                }
            }
            return View(students);
        }
```

Comment: `IEnumerable<MasterTab> resResult = result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;` Here return type is string. SO, what you need to do is first use string result = assign result;  then convert it using newtonsoft or other libraries to `IEnumerable<MasterTab>`

Answer (score 3):

Either way, then we can call the `ApiController` directly from your `MVC` controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var listOfFiles = new MarketingController().GetMarketing();

        return View(listOfFiles);
    }
}
```

If we have our `WebApi` as a different project altogether in the same solution then we can call the same from `MVC` controller like below:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
        {
            string apiUrl = "http://localhost:58764/api/Marketing/GetMarketing";

            using (HttpClient client=new HttpClient())
            {
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri(apiUrl);
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

                HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(apiUrl);
                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    var data = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    EntityType entity = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<EntityType>(data);

                }


            }
            return View();

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't cast type string as type MasterTab. I guess the WebApi service returns data in JSON format. Try to use Newtonsoft.Json to deserialize string response into MasterTab collection.

https://www.newtonsoft.com/json